# GGPlot 2 colour points by catagorical data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to colour the scatter plot by catagorical data.
At the moment GGplot2 just colours them red and in the legend shows Region. Region is the column name for the catagorical data.

```
chart <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = `CO2 Emissions per Capita 2016  (tons)`, y = `Average Weekly Workplace Earnings 2016  (Â£)`, colour = 'Region'))
chart + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes in `aes()`. 
Write `color = Region` or color = `Region` with backquotes.